# I can await fs.readdir but I don't know why

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, electron

https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue

I used this template to make electron.

And I am using this library.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v11.x/api/fs.html

By this document, I can write like this.

```
await fs.readdir
```

But the electron template, it is using electron@2.0.4 and which is using node@8.9.3.

So I checked here.

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/fs.html

It looks like the function doesn't return promise.

But I actually can await fs functions using fs-extra in electron@2.0.4.

Both develop and build.

Why is this?

result of

```
console.log(fs.readdir())
```

Is like below.

[image]

It's Promise.

But I don't know why I can do this in electron@2.0.4.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? await can replace `.then()` in Promises. you can use it like this as well: `fs.readdir().then((...args) => {....your handler})`.

Comment: I just want to know the reason why I can awati fs-extra functions in lower then node10.

Comment: fs-extra promisifies basic fs functions, that's all. From readme: "fs-extra is a drop in replacement for native fs. All methods in fs are attached to fs-extra. All fs methods return promises if the callback isn't passed."

Comment: Yes! And this is very good thing! I prefer fs-extra so much!!!! So useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use fs module in node v8. the return value will be passed to callback function

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir(dir, function(err, list) {

// do your logic with list array

})
```

Comment: Thank you I know that. I was just wondering why there is no fs/promise on node v8 but fs-extra funcitons return Promise. I thought it's just because fs-extra was created like that.

Comment: yes, they might put a promise wrapper to this function.

Comment: This confused me so much because in "fs-extra" node v10, fs.Dirent class exists, and on "fs-extra" node v8 fs.Dirent class does not exist. And this is same as "fs". Dirent class exists in "fs" node v10 and doesn't exist in "fs" v8. So, I thought "fs-extra" requires "fs", "fs-extra" and "fs" are pretty much same.  I thought that if "fs" node v8 is not promisified, "fs-extra" node v8 is neither promisified. But "fs-extra" node v8 functions are promisified. And this is very good thing I think. I prefer fs-extra. But I just got confused so I ask this question.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Node > 8.16 (I believe), you can use `promisify` in the `utils` module:

```
const { promisify } = require('utils');
const fs = require('fs');
const readdir = promisify(fs.readdir);

(async () => {
  const res = await readdir('./path');
  console.log(res);
})();
```

Comment: Thank you. But what I was wondering is little bit different. If you can, please look at conversation with Sharvin K at above. I am sorry.

Answer (score -3):

Sorry, I am not good at English.

And, I am a beginner web developer.

This is just an anticipation.

I saw package.json of "fs-extra".

And I could not find "fs" inside that.

It is using a library called "graceful-fs", but this library does not require "fs" neither.

Maybe, "fs-extra" is not relevant to "fs".

And it has own logic that is already promisified even in node lower than verstion10.

Any one know the truth?